# If $f(1) = a$, $f(2n) = f(n)$ and $f(2n + 1) = f(n) - b$ for $f : \Bbb N \to \Bbb R$ and $a,b \in \Bbb Z$, find $\sum^{n}_{r = 1} f(r)$

Tags: summation, recurrence-relations

> If $f(1) = a$, $f(2n) = f(n)$ and $f(2n + 1) = f(n) - b$ for $f : \Bbb N  \to \Bbb R$ and $a,b \in \Bbb Z$, find $$\sum^{100}_{r = 1} f(r)$$.

It is easy to see that $f(2^m) = a$ for $m \in \Bbb N$.

Calculating some values of $f$,

$f(1) = a$

$f(2) = a$

$f(3)=f(2 \cdot 1 + 1) = f(1) - b = a-b$,

$f(5)=f(2 \cdot 2 + 1) = f(2) - b = a-b$,

$f(6) = f(3) = a- b$

So,

$$\begin{align}\sum_{r = 1}^{100} f(r) &= \sum_{r = 1}^{49} f(2r + 1) + \sum_{ r }^{50} f(2r)\\ &= \sum^{50}_{r = 1}f(r) - 49 b - f(50) + \sum^{50}_{r = 1}f(r)\\ &= 2\sum_{r= 1}^{50}f(r) - 49b -f(50) \\ &=  2\left(2\sum_{r= 1}^{24}f(r) -
 24b + f(25)\right) - 49b -f(50)\\ &=   2\left(2\left(2\sum_{r= 1}^{12}f(r) -11b - f(12)\right)- 24b + f(25)\right) - 49b -f(50) \\ &=   2\left(2\left(2\left(2\sum_{r= 1}^{6}f(r) - f(6) - 5b\right) -11b - f(12)\right)- 24b + f(25)\right) - 49b -f(50) \\ &=  2f(25) - f(50) -
 181b -4f(12)-8f(6) + 16\sum^6_{r=0} f(r)\\ &= 79a -219b  \end{align}$$

Is this correct ? the numbers don't look nice.

Any easier way to find this sum ?

Comment: Idk if this helps, but $$\begin{align}&f(2^m)&&=a\\&f(2^m+1)&&=a-b\\&f(2^m+2)&&=a-b\\&f(2^m+2+1)&&=a-2b\\&f(2^m+2^2+2)&&=a-2b\\&f(2^m+2^2+2+1)&&=a-3b\\&\qquad\vdots&&\qquad\vdots\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an approach which may not be simpler than what you done for $n = 100$.
However, it provide a formula which will be easier to implement and more efficient to compute for larger $n$.

---

For any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $(\cdots a_3a_2a_1a_0)_2$ be its binary representation. i.e.,

$$n = a_0 + a_1 \cdot 2 + a_2 \cdot 2^2 + a_3 \cdot 2^3 + \cdots\quad\text{ where }\quad a_k \in \{ 0, 1 \}$$

Let $\theta_k(n)$ be the coefficient $a_k$ and ${\rm pop}(n)$ be the number of $1$'s in the binary representation of $n$. More precisely, 
$${\rm pop}(n) \stackrel{def}{=} \#\{ k : a_k = 1 \} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k
= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \theta_k(n)
$$

It is easy to see ${\rm pop}(n)$ satisfies the recurrence relation:

$${\rm pop}(1) = 1,\quad {\rm pop}(2n) = {\rm pop}(n)\quad\text{ and }\quad
{\rm pop}(2n+1) = {\rm pop}(n) + 1$$

Compare this to that of $f(n)$, we find
$$f(n) = (a+b) - b\cdot{\rm pop}(n)$$
This leads to
$$\sum_{r=1}^n f(r) = (a+b)n - b \sum_{r=1}^n{\rm pop}(r)
= (a+b)n - b\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{r=1}^n\theta_k(r)$$
The task of finding the sum of $f(r)$ reduce to computation of $\sum\limits_{r=1}^n \theta_k(r) = \sum\limits_{r=0}^n \theta_k(r)$ for various $k$.
i.e. the number of $r: 0 \le r \le n$ whose coefficient $a_k$ is $1$.

One can verify that

- If $m = \lfloor \frac{n+1}{2^k} \rfloor$ is even, there is $\frac{m}{2}$ block of $2^k$ consecutive integers whose $a_k = 1$.
- If $m = \lfloor \frac{n+1}{2^k}\rfloor$ is odd, there is $\frac{m+1}{2}$ block of
  $2^k$ consecutive integers whose $a_k = 0$.

If we define a function $\phi(x)$ over $\mathbb{R}$ by
$$\phi(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac12\lfloor x \rfloor, & \lfloor x \rfloor \text{ is even}\\
x - \frac12 \lfloor x+1 \rfloor & \lfloor x \rfloor \text{ is odd}\\
\end{cases}
$$
We will have

$$\sum_{r=0}^n \theta_k(r) = 2^k \phi\left(\frac{n+1}{2^k}\right)
\quad\implies\quad
\sum_{r=1}^n f(r) = (a+b) n - b \sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^k \phi\left(\frac{n+1}{2^k}\right)
$$
Apply this to the case $n = 100$ and notice

- $\phi\left(101/2^0\right) = \phi(101)   = 101-51 = 50$
- $\phi\left(101/2^1\right) = \phi(50.5)  = 25$
- $\phi\left(101/2^2\right) = \phi(25.25) = 25.25 - 13 = 12.25$
- $\phi\left(101/2^3\right) = \phi(12.625) = 6$
- $\phi\left(101/2^4\right) = \phi(6.3125) = 3$
- $\phi\left(101/2^5\right) = \phi(3.15625) = 3.15625 - 2 = 1.15625$
- $\phi\left(101/2^6\right) = \phi(1.578125) = 1.578125 - 1 = 0.578125$
- $\phi\left(101/2^k\right) = 0$ for all $k > 6$, we obtain

Combine these, we get
$$\begin{align}\sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^k\phi\left(\frac{101}{2^k}\right)
&= 50 + 2\cdot 25 + 2^2 \cdot 12.25 + 2^3 \cdot 6 + 2^4 \cdot 3 + 2^5 \cdot 1.15625 + 2^6 \cdot 0.578125\\ 
&= 50 + 50 + 49 + 48 + 48 + 37 + 37 = 319
\end{align}
$$
which leads to $\displaystyle\;\sum_{r=1}^{100} f(r) = 100a - 219b$.

BTW, you are dropping some $a$ in your computation. You get the right coefficient for $b$ but wrong one for $a$. If I didn't make any mistake, it should be:

$$\small
\begin{align}
\sum_{r = 1}^{100} f(r) 
&= a + \sum_{r = 1}^{49} f(2r + 1) + \sum_{ r }^{50} f(2r)\\ 
&= a + \sum^{50}_{r = 1}f(r) - 49 b - f(50) + \sum^{50}_{r = 1}f(r)\\ 
&= a + 2\sum_{r= 1}^{50}f(r) - 49b -f(50) \\ 
&= a + 2\left(a + 2\sum_{r= 1}^{24}f(r) -
 24b + f(25)\right) - 49b -f(50)\\ 
&= 3a +  2\left(2\left(a + 2\sum_{r= 1}^{12}f(r) -11b - f(12)\right)- 24b + f(25)\right) - 49b -f(50) \\ 
&= 7a +  2\left(2\left(2\left(a + 2\sum_{r= 1}^{6}f(r) - f(6) - 5b\right) -11b - f(12)\right)- 24b + f(25)\right) - 49b -f(50) \\ 
&= 15a + 2f(25) - f(50) - 181b -4f(12)-8f(6) + 16\sum^6_{r=0} f(r)\\ 
&= 100a -219b
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Why is $\sum\limits_{r=1}^n \theta_k(r) = \sum\limits_{r=0}^n \theta_k(r)$ ? other than that I understand your method. Just of curiosity I want to know in which type of math books (like analysis, calculus ,. .. ) does this type of summation techniques are described ?

Comment: This is because the binary representation of $0$ consists only of $0$. So $\theta_k(0) = 0$ for all $k$. I include $r = 0$ there because it let me easier to see why $\frac{n+1}{2^k}$ instead of $\frac{n}{2^k}$ appear in the formula. I didn't come up the formula myself, I have computed a few $\sum_{r=1}^n {\rm pop}(r)$ by computer and do an OEIS search. I find the formula in OEIS [A000788](https://oeis.org/A000788). There are other recursive formula there but this one seems easier to use.